# v8 upgrade show this error TypeError: action.apply is not a function

Tags: react-native, v8

we decide to upgrade our Runtime from Hermes to v8 it should fix some issues that we have. And all works fine except our storage library. We are using:

```
    "react-native-mmkv-storage": "^0.6.6",
    "react-native-v8": ">=0.64.1-patch.0 <0.64.2",
    "v8-android-jit": "9.88.0",
    "react-native": "0.64.1"
```

and in code we are trying to store some data like this:

```
export const setItem = async (key: string, value: string): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await MMKVwithEncryption.setStringAsync(key, value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error)
  }
};
```

This function is called in app context when we want to store some data. All works fine when we are using Hermes but when we switch to v8 it show this error:
`ERROR:  [TypeError: action.apply is not a function]`

Any solution or idea on how to handle this error?

Comment: Did you tried `npm install graceful-fs --save-dev`?

Comment: i will ... give me a sec

Comment: should I do something extra or just add this library to the project? I just add it and no changes. The issue is still there...

Comment: Nono I just had a similar problem and I solved installing this library. Sorry to not be more helpful.